# How to save entry field values to disk in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an intrepid young friend who asked me to write a script that could create configuration (text) files for a science program he needs, and asked if I could hack together a GUI in Python that would simplify the process.  I've been able to piece together a bit of it that would provide him a GUI to enter in a few of the values he needs, but am not quite sure how to save these values via Tkinter.  Can any of you give me any suggestions on possible solutions?

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
import Tkinter
from tkFileDialog import *

window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.title('File Generator for Adam!')

# create file menu


# create a label widget called lbl
lbl = Tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter the imin value for Min")
# create matching text entry widget called ent
ent = Tkinter.Entry(window)

lbl2 = Tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter the ntx value for Min")
ent2 = Tkinter.Entry(window)

# pack (add) widgets to window
lbl.pack()
ent.pack()
lbl2.pack()
ent2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to set a string variable object using tkinter (`Tkinter.StringVar()`), then set the property for your entries to the corresponging variables. Something like this:

```
window = Tkinter.Tk()
ent1var = Tkinter.StringVar()
ent1 = Tkinter.Entry(window, textvarible=ent1var)
ent1.pack()
```

To retrieve what is in `ent1` you need to run the `get()` method on `ent1var`.

```
def getent1():
    return ent1var.get()
```

You can the use this above definition in a button like so:

```
ent1but = Tkinter.Button(window, text="Show ent1", command=getent1)
ent1but.pack()
```

Comment: hmm, should I consider switching over to wxPython then?  Seems like it'd be the more Pythonic way to achieve this goal.

Comment: Tkinter is great for dead simple UI. I've found that wxPython is much much more powerful, but it's 10x more difficult to get everything squared away. It really comes down to the right tool for the job. If it's just a few interface items I would go with Tkinter in a heartbeat. If it needs to be more powerful/look petty, wxPython is what I lean towards.

Comment: Quiet often I'll use Tkinter (and py2exe) in place of handing my coworkers a command line operated file so that they can use a file chooser in the UI they're familiar with.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Kyrubas . I'll see if I can manage to figure out how to user Tkinter to do this.  You've certainly given me a good lead!  Thanks again :-)

Comment: @kyrubas: re "you can't directly call the text/data out of an object in Tkinter." - that's completely false. Also, you don't need to use an instance of `StringVar`. You _can_, but it's not necessary. All widgets have a way to access their own data.

Comment: @BryanOakley and @n1c9, I stand corrected. I just tried it out without a `StringVar` and it works just fine. I'll update my answer to reflect that it is one method of use. This is an instance of where I had learned one way to use Tkinter quite a while ago and have not since had reason to investigate other ways to use it. I'm not quite sure why I came to solely use `StringVar` in Tkinter.

Answer (score 3):

The entry widget has a `get`method, which is well documented.

```
ent1 = Tkinter.Entry(window)
...
print "the data is " + ent1.get()
```

Typically you would write a function that calls the `get` method on your entry widgets, and then call that function from a button. Once you have the data, you save it to a file like you save any other data.

```
def save_data():
    with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(ent1.get() + "\n")
        f.write(ent2.get() + "\n")
...
button = Tkinter.Button(window, text="Save", command=save_data)
```